# ./cache on Ubuntu 20.04 uses enormous size

Tags: files

I run virtual machine Ubuntu 20.04. The HDD I give to this OS is 200 GB, and I see that it is almost full. Surely I do not use so much space with the programs I have. After searching on stackoverflow/askubuntu I found a program **ncdu** and I ran it. I found that ./cache consumes 120 GB!!! What is this? Can I delete it?

Comment: Can you see what application / directory that is filling up in .cache ? Depending on what i is, it can be deleted, or you might have to adjust caching in the application to stop it from comming back.

Comment: Is there a command to see this? Otherwise it shows me only ./cache and the size consumed

Comment: cd into ,cache, and use ndcu there. Or navigate in ndcu by moving the marker up or down and press Enter on the directory you want to enter.

Comment: Ok, I did it. It assigns 127.GB to /vmware, 938.3MB to /tracker, 615,2MB to /mozilla, 453,8 MB to /pip all the rest are under 5 MB/each. Do you see something strange?

Comment: So Vmware is using 127 GB cache ... If you are using vmware, you might ask in a vmware forum what that are cached, if it can be controlled and if it can be deleted. I don't use vmware, so I can't tell.

Comment: What is `./cache`? Please provide absolute path.

Comment: Yes this is: /home/UbuntuUser/.cache

Comment: Most likely /var/cache/apt/archive.